# Study of the Laplacian on the Hyperbolic plane

Tags: spectral-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

What's a good reference for the simplest case? I'm interested in the spectral theory of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the upper half plane (domain, self-adjoint extension, etc.). I only need this for the 2D case, not the quotient space with a group (or other more elaborate cases).

Comment: I have edited my answer with two more references. Bump is very good, especially chapter 2.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46532/laplace-beltrami-operator-on-surfaces

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few references for the study of the hyperbolic Laplacian. I'm not sure that any of them are exactly what you're looking for, but they should paint the picture well enough.

- Audrey Terras, *Harmonic Analysis on Symmetric Spaces and Applications*, vol. I and II
- Peter Buser, *Geometry and Spectra of Compact Riemann Surfaces*
- Isaac Chavel, *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry*

---

Edited much later: Another very good reference that I've recently come across is

- Daniel Bump, *Automorphic Forms and Representations*
- Gelfand, Graev, and Piatetsky-Shapiro, *Representation Theory and Automorphic Functions,* may also be of interest to you.